# ¿Porque no me cargan los iconos?

Tags: html, css, icons

resulta que no me cargan los iconos , al usar el kit y no se el porque , adjunto imagen : [image: Me muestra asi]

[image: El codigo de icono]

[image: Cabecera]

De antemano Muchas Gracias !

pd: Fontawesome

Comment: te faltan las [webfonts](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/host-yourself/webfonts)

Comment: Tienes que cargarle els CSS del fontawesome que alli es donde carga las fuentes de los icono. Para que se te vean

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el recorrido inicial para elaborar una [buena pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). crea un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable, de lo contrario tu pregunta terminara cerrada.

Comment: Lo siento, pero es dificil ayudar cuando el código está en una imagen, pues nos da pereza intentar reproducir tu error si tenemos que teclear todo eso para intentarlo. Planteate no pegar código como imagen y sí como texto, y quizas consigas mejores ayudas. Léete [ask] y lo del [example] para aprender a realizar buenas preguntas, gracias.

Comment: @masterguru Gracias por la respuesta masterguru! , lo lamento, es que soy nuevo jaja, tomare tu consejo ! , Ya logre solucionarlo! , Igualmente Muchas Gracias!